# Laravel eloquent query with

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

This query returns all groups with an id however it also returns all the products to every group.

```
$groups = \App\Group::where('campaign_id', $id)->with('product')->get();
    dd($groups->toArray());array:2 [▼
```

This is the output.

```
0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 24
    "campaign_id" => "TRE36934"
    "group_name" => "group2"
    "created_at" => "2017-05-17 16:14:55"
    "updated_at" => null
    "product" => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:8 [▶]
      1 => array:8 [▶]
      2 => array:8 [▶]
      3 => array:8 [▶]
```

I am trying to return the groups with same id. Can I somehow query? The join in the id in the groups table and the foreign key in call 'group' in the group table.

Comment: I am trying to return the groups with same id. mean?

Comment: Trying to run products that belong to a group. So the product array. Should be products with the same camapign_id.

Answer (score 2):

A simple inner join should suffice here, right?

```
$groups = \App\Group::join('product', 'group.campaign_id', '=', 'product.group')
                    ->where('group.campaign_id', $id)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
$groups = Group::join('product', 'group.campaign_id', '=', 'product.group')
                    ->where('group.campaign_id', $id)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your product with the same campaing id, you can do the following :

```
$products = Product::get()->groupBy('campaign_id');
```

Or you can do it directly from SQL

So, if you want a collection of Product, use your product model :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you may try this:

```
$group = \App\Group::where('campaign_id', $id)->get();
$group->load('products');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies they all got me a bit cloer

```
$products = \App\Product::join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'products.group')->get()->groupBy('group');
```

The basic groupby by **Mathieu Ferre** got me close. I added a join with a groupby as suggested by **Mozammil** on the name to give me

```
$products = \App\Product::join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'products.group')->get()->groupBy('group_name');
```